# Extends parent blocks from embed template

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to inject inside the styles and scripts blocks in my layout new values, but from the embed block.
Of course it throws the error `Calling "parent" outside a block is forbidden.`.
Is there any workaround ?

**layout.html.twig:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block style %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>

        {% block content "" %}

        {% block scripts %}
            <script src="foo.js"></script>
        {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**list.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% embed datatable.html.twig %}
        {% block tbody %}
            <tr>
                <td>my awesome table</td>
            </tr>
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

**datatable.html.twig:**

```
<table id="myDatatable">
    <tbody>
        {% block tbody "" %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% block styles %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dataTables.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="dataTables.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

(And I cant/wont use the blocks `scripts` and `styles` inside the `list.html.twig`. They are part of the datatable template, it will not make any sens to define theme in the `list.html.twig`.).
And sadly I cant use `use` because this function does not support dynamics properties, only strings.

[From the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/use.html) :

> Because use statements are resolved independently of the context passed to the template, the template reference cannot be an expression.

Comment: includes/embeds can't change/alter blocks in the template from which it was included from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, includes/embeds can't alter blocks from their includer.
That said there is an extension available that could solve your problem.

This `Deferred Twig Extension` can be found [here](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred)

Basically the node postpones the execution of a said block. 
This way you can create a variable that holds all of your javascript links and output them. This can be seen in the [advanced](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred#user-content-advanced-example) example found on the github.

*credits to [Eugene Leonovich](https://github.com/rybakit) for making this extension*

Comment: Seems to be an interesting way to proceed, in a perfect world I would prefer not to use any bundle for this