# Overriding parent variable in twig

Tags: php, twig, slim, slim-3, twig-extension

I have an extension that I am putting together with twig / PHP.

My extension looks for a line like the following:

```
{% module 'blog' with {'controller':'controllers/posts.php', 'view':'templates/posts.html'} %}
```

Inside my token parser I look up the path for the controller (posts.php) and include the file - this is all working fine.

Inside the "posts.php" file I want to override the $context or otherwise override the variables in the parent template I am extending, however, it seems that $context is not passed by reference and thus cannot be overwritten.

My (base.html) template file looks like this (shortened for easier reading).

```
<title>{{meta.title}}</title>
{% block content %} Default  content {% endblock %}
```

My index.html (template that extends base.html) looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% module 'blog' with {'controller':'controllers/posts.php', 'view':'templates/posts.html'} %}
{% endblock %}
```

Inside "posts.php" I am (attempting) overriding of $context (which is actually the variables the template gets rendered with) like this:

```
$context['meta']['title'] = microtime(true);
```

And wrapping the entire functionality is obviously the render method (from Slimphp - simplified for brevity)

```
$twig->render('index.html', ['meta'=>['title'=>'Set from slim']]);
```

The meta.title variable is always set to "Set from slim" in the parent template, no matter what I try I cannot override it.

I have tried late static binding, getting/setting variables statically using a container class but no matter what I try the parent is always rendered with the original "Set from slim" variable value. I have pin pointed this down to the fact that $context is not passed by reference around twig.

Surely someone in the past has hit this wall before and knows a work around?

Please help!

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The suggested answer does not answer the question. It attemps to defer rendering from inside the template file, I wish to override variables from a different file at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extends parent blocks from embed template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702118/extends-parent-blocks-from-embed-template)

Comment: Watch the extension i've linked in there. It should give you a direction

Comment: Thanks but that attemps to set variables inside the template doesn't it? I am looking to set / override them from a different included file

Comment: You need to work with [globals](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred#user-content-advanced-example) as each template has it own scope, you can't alter that with an extension.

Comment: I;ve already tried using addGlobal and overwriting that global in the include file. It still does not work.

Comment: ... And thats why i've posted that extension. If you defer the block and read out the global it will contain the changed value

Comment: The extension defers the rendering by using ob_* functions. This is NOT what I am trying to achieve. As I've explained, I am trying to override $context from inside an included file (php)... NOT from an included template file

Comment: That is basically the same thing.. Twig templates are compiled into `PHP` files. You are just altering the source output of the included template with your own code, which still can't access the parents context. You would need to modify and create your own `Twig_Environment` to change how contexts are passed down to templates

Comment: Regardless of how the contexts are passed, if my parent template calls a function say variables.get('meta.title') and from my child template an included php file sets that variable via a late static binding then surely the interpreter cannot resolve the response until that last forwarding call which would be after my child function has been renderd - thus including the php file that sets the variable

Comment: Update:

I've installed the deferred extension and it still doens't do what I require because it sets or tries to set the variable from the template file.

Comment: late static binding will not solve anything as output in a twig template is `echo'd` and stored in the `ob_buffer` instantly.  Watch the example with the global [here][https://github.com/rybakit/twig-extensions-deferred#user-content-advanced-example)

Comment: I've used the extension exactly how it's described using a global and it does not do what I am trying to accomplish.

Once again. I am trying to change the variables in an included php file NOT from twig via {% include %} or {% enxtends %} etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's absolutely impossible to do this.

In the end I wrote some code to load the template file, parse it using regex to extract the `{% module .... %}` line, grab the controller, cache it to an array list of controllers to include in said page, then next time instead of parsing I can just lookup the CRC of the view in question (using `filemtime($path);`) to see if it's changed, then return the list of includes to include which set the variables prior to the render being called