# Choose twig block process order

Tags: twig

I want to make modular css load with instruction in twig

```
{{ addCss("csspath") }}
{# rest of template #}
```

and then write all css in a twig block in my html header like this :

```
{% block css %}
    {{ writeCss() }}
{% endblock %}
```

My custom function work well, all css store with `addCss` will be write by `writeCss` but I have some problem with twig processing order. Css needs to be in `head` html tag and because of that twig process `writeCss` before all my `addCss` call.

I've made some test to guess twig process order by i have no ideo of how control it.

Comment: You  are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712220/446594)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed ! thanks @DarkBee I've searching all morning but doesn't found it !

Comment: No problem, when I needed such a mechanism i've spent quite some time as well untill I found that plugin