# How can I change the default behavior for invalid variables in Twig?

Tags: twig

Twig normally replaces variables that do not exist with a null value. I'd like to change this default behavior so that Twig keeps the variable intact so I can parse it later.

For example, if `path` is defined as '/assets' but `screen.name` is not defined, the following template snippet:

```
{{path}}/js/{{screen}}.js
```

will become:

```
/assets/js/.js
```

But what I want is:

```
/assets/js/{{screen}}.js
```

so that the variable can be parsed again later after it gets some value. Please keep in mind that using the *default* filter (`{{path}}/js/{{screen|default('{{screen}}')}}.js`) is cumbersome and would have to be repeated for each and every variable so it is not a solution for me.

Is there a way to override this default behavior at all? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Twig does not replace any variables with `null` when a variable is not defined. It is because `debug` is set to false that `twig` suppresses  error messages about undefined variables

Comment: Have a look at the [deffered twig extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702118/extends-parent-blocks-from-embed-template). More information about what it is over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712220/446594)

Comment: According to the doc: If `strict_variables` set to false, Twig will silently ignore invalid variables (variables and or attributes/methods that do not exist) and replace them _with a null value_. If `debug` is set to true, it says the generated templates have a __toString() method that you can use to display the generated nodes, but I found no working examples on how to do that.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682190/how-to-get-the-output-of-tostring-when-using-debug-mode-for-twig) has a related, unanswered question. I believe being able to use or override the `__toString()` method would be ideal, but I can't even find it in the template object, `debug` being set to `true` or not.

Comment: Not sure what you're aiming at. Did you have a look at the extension I've linked you? It will solve your problem

Comment: I'm writing a preprocessor that will process some templates in a certain order. I want to render the known variables but keep the ones that are not defined intact for the next pass, as illustrated in the code above, and so on.

At first it seemed that `debug` / `__toString()` would do it, but I can't find any php code about using it. And the `__toString()` method does not show up in the Twig template object.

Thanks for the deferred twig extension tip, I'll try it. Too bad ther's not a simpler solution using Twig alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192071/discussion-between-rubem-pechansky-and-darkbee).

Comment: I know its been a while, but I'm looking for a way to do this as well. Has anyone had any success?