# Is there a way of rendering Twig blocks in a second loop?

Tags: twig

Let‘s say we spread teasers of news posts all over a content page. Some of them are set by the editor and all others should be dynamically loaded. The dynamic loader has to respect the news that are set by the editor to not show the same news multiple times.

The tricky part is when the editor places a news after a dynamic area.

What I try to do is to render the whole page except the dynamic parts, collect the IDs of the set news to exclude them from the dynamic ones in the deferred blocks.

**Speaking in Code:**

Our page has the following template:

```
<div class="container">
    {# AREA 1 – dynamic area that should not show news with ID 1 #}
    {% include 'news-dynamic.html.twig' %}

    {# AREA 2 – contains news with ID 1, set by editor #}
    {% include 'news-static.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

Content of `news-dynamic.html.twig`:

```
{# news_id_loaded_by_service – must not have the ID 1 #}
{%- set news_id_loaded_by_service = get_relevant_news(seen_news) -%}
{%- do seen_news.append(news_id_loaded_by_service) -%}

{# HTML – deferred #}
<pre>{{ seen_news|join(', ') }}</pre>
<pre>{{ news_id_loaded_by_service }}</pre>
<hr>
```

Content of `news-static.html.twig`:

```
{%- set news_id_set_by_editor = 1 -%}
{%- do seen_news.append(news_id_set_by_editor) -%}

{# HTML – rendered instantly #}
<pre>{{ seen_news|join(', ') }}</pre>
<pre>{{ news_id_set_by_editor }}</pre>
<hr>
```

Desired output:

```
2, 1
2
---
2, 1
1
---
```

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/rybakit/twig-deferred-extension) what you are looking for?

Comment: Some extra information about the plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702118/extends-parent-blocks-from-embed-template)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately blocks marked as deferred are only deferred on the same level. Nested deferred blocks are rendered normally.