# Does twig have the equivalent of blades "@push" and or "@stack"

Tags: twig

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#stacks

basically it lets you overwrite `block` multiple times, but instead of overwriting each other, each call appends to the `block`.

E.g.

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->
 
    @stack('myscripts')
</head>
```

```
@push('myscripts')
    <script src="/example11.js"></script>
@endpush
```

```
@push('myscripts')
    <script src="/example22.js"></script>
@endpush
```

results in

```
<head>
    <!-- Head Contents -->
 
    <script src="/example11.js"></script>
    <script src="/example22.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extends parent blocks from embed template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702118/extends-parent-blocks-from-embed-template)

Comment: Not by default no, but have a look at my answer in the question I've marked as dupe, especially the paragraph about the advanced example.

Comment: I appreciate your answer (which was: no). I'm not a big fan of using other peoples bundles... I think there should be probably simpler solutions to adding js assets. But my example was just a js asset. It doesnt NEED to be a string javascript asset, does that make sense? push and stack works with everything. Random inline javascript, entire tags... does that make sense?

Comment: Then the answer is: No there is no equivalent by default

Comment: @DarkBee actually thinking about it... twig has something that is called block assignments in jinja2... it is assignment of chunk of text to variables. You could use that, append it to a global list or whatever, and then in the footer at the very end, overwrite some block where you would have `@stack`, and just output all entries of the list. If that works, it should be same result.

Comment: That would work, if you would want to place the snippet near the closing `</body>` tag yes